# I want to use "el-upload" to upload images and documents, but I want to display the images

Tags: element

I want to use "el-upload" to upload images and documents, but I want to display the images. If "list-type='picture-card'" is used, the document will also be shown with an incorrect cover. So is there any way I can upload files that show images thumbnails, documents that show names?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOR4t.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<el-upload
     action=""
     ref="upload"
     :auto-upload="false"
     :on-change="onchange">
  <el-button slot="trigger" size="small" type="primary">Click to Upload</el-button>
 </el-upload>
 <el-image 
    style="width: 100px; height: 100px"
    :src="fileList[0]" 
    :preview-src-list="fileList">
  </el-image>

data() {
  return {
   fileList: []
 }
}, methods: {
   onchange(file, fileList){
     this.fileList.push(URL.createObjectURL(file.raw))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div class="upload-file">
    <el-upload
      multiple
      :action="uploadFileUrl"
      :before-upload="handleBeforeUpload"
      :file-list="fileList"
      :limit="limit"
      :on-error="handleUploadError"
      :on-exceed="handleExceed"
      :on-success="handleUploadSuccess"
      :show-file-list="false"
      :headers="headers"
      class="upload-file-uploader"
      ref="upload"
    >
      <!-- 上传按钮 -->
      <el-button type="primary">选取文件</el-button>
    </el-upload>
    <!-- 上传提示 -->
    <!-- <div class="el-upload__tip" v-if="showTip">
      请上传
      <template v-if="fileSize"> 大小不超过 <b style="color: #f56c6c">{{ fileSize }}MB</b> </template>
      <template v-if="fileType"> 格式为 <b style="color: #f56c6c">{{ fileType.join("/") }}</b> </template>
      的文件
    </div> -->
    <!-- 文件列表 -->
    <transition-group
      class="upload-file-list el-upload-list el-upload-list--text"
      name="el-fade-in-linear"
      tag="ul"
    >
      <li
        :key="file.uid"
        class="el-upload-list__item ele-upload-list__item-content"
        v-for="(file, index) in fileList">
        <el-link
          :href="`${baseUrl}${file.url}`"
          :underline="false"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <span class="el-icon-document"> {{ getFileName(file.name) }} </span>
        </el-link>
        <div class="ele-upload-list__item-content-action">
          <el-link :underline="false" @click="handleDelete(index)" type="danger"
            >删除</el-link
          >
        </div>
      </li>
    </transition-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { getToken } from "@/utils/auth";

const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: [String, Object, Array],
  // 数量限制
  limit: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1,
  },
  // 大小限制(MB)
  fileSize: {
    type: Number,
    default: 2,
  },
  // 文件类型, 例如['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']
  fileType: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => ["png", "jpg", "gif"],
  },
  // 是否显示提示
  isShowTip: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
});

const { proxy } = getCurrentInstance();
const emit = defineEmits();
const number = ref(0);
const uploadList = ref([]);
const baseUrl = "URL HERE";
const uploadFileUrl = baseUrl + "Folder_URL"; // 
const headers = ref({ Authorization: "Bearer " + getToken() });
const fileList = ref([]);
const showTip = computed(
  () => props.isShowTip && (props.fileType || props.fileSize)
);

watch(
  () => props.modelValue,
  (val) => {
    if (val) {
      let temp = 1;
     
      const list = Array.isArray(val) ? val : props.modelValue.split(",");
      
      fileList.value = list.map((item) => {
        if (typeof item === "string") {
          item = { name: item, url: item };
        }
        item.uid = item.uid || new Date().getTime() + temp++;
        return item;


      });
    } else {
      fileList.value = [];
      return [];
    }
  },
  { deep: true, immediate: true }
);


function handleBeforeUpload(file) {
 
  if (props.fileType.length) {
    let fileExtension = "";
    if (file.name.lastIndexOf(".") > -1) {
      fileExtension = file.name.slice(file.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    }
    const isTypeOk = props.fileType.some((type) => {
      if (file.type.indexOf(type) > -1) return true;
      if (fileExtension && fileExtension.indexOf(type) > -1) return true;
      return false;
    });
    if (!isTypeOk) {
      proxy.$modal.msgError(
       ${props.fileType.join("/")}
      );
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  if (props.fileSize) {
    const isLt = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < props.fileSize;
    if (!isLt) {
      proxy.$modal.msgError(`上传文件大小不能超过 ${props.fileSize} MB!`);
      return false;
    }
  }
  proxy.$modal.loading("正在上传文件，请稍候...");
  number.value++;
  return true;
}


function handleExceed() {
  proxy.$modal.msgError(`上传文件数量不能超过 ${props.limit} 个!`);
}


function handleUploadError(err) {
  proxy.$modal.msgError("上传文件失败");
}

// 上传成功回调
function handleUploadSuccess(res, file) {
  uploadList.value.push({ name: res.fileName, url: res.fileName });
  if (uploadList.value.length === number.value) {
    fileList.value = fileList.value
      .filter((f) => f.url !== undefined)
      .concat(uploadList.value);
    uploadList.value = [];
    number.value = 0;
    emit("update:modelValue", listToString(fileList.value));
    proxy.$modal.closeLoading();

    console.log("url", file);
  }
}

// 删除文件
function handleDelete(index) {
  fileList.value.splice(index, 1);
  emit("update:modelValue", listToString(fileList.value));
}

// 获取文件名称
function getFileName(name) {
  if (name.lastIndexOf("/") > -1) {
    return name.slice(name.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

// 对象转成指定字符串分隔
function listToString(list, separator) {
  let strs = "";
  separator = separator || ",";
  for (let i in list) {
    if (undefined !== list[i].url) {
      strs += list[i].url + separator;
    }
  }
  return strs != "" ? strs.substr(0, strs.length - 1) : "";
}
</script>


//tu

<style scoped lang="scss">
.upload-file-uploader {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.upload-file-list .el-upload-list__item {
  border: 1px solid #e4e7ed;
  line-height: 2;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.upload-file-list .ele-upload-list__item-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: inherit;
}
.ele-upload-list__item-content-action .el-link {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).